# Strange view effect when navigating and changing visibility of navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, show-hide

I have a `UINavigationController` and I want its root view controller to hide the navigation bar, so I wrote this in the root view controller's class:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

This effectively hides the navigation bar. This root view controller has a button that pushes a new view controller when tapped. I want this second view controller to show the navigation bar, so in its subclass:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

Navigation bar is then shown, but when I tap its back button and I navigate back to the previous view controller (the one I wanted to hide the navigation bar), for an instant at the top of its view it is shown a black space where the navigation bar should be, and finally the view "goes" to the top of the screen again.

How could I avoid this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the navigation bar hidden in viewWillAppear.

`override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}`